# Django - ModelForm - What if the instance does not exist yet?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a modelForm that use instance, but the first time the user access the form, the instance does not exist yet. If the instance does not exist there would be an empty form.

Whats is the best way to handle that? Also, how is it possible to delete the instance in the form?

Should I use modelformset_factory with max_number = 1, can_delete= True instead?

view.py:

```
def setLayerLabel(request, map_id, layerMapOptions_id):
    layerMapOptions = LayerMapOptions.objects.get(pk=layerMapOptions_id)
    layerLabel_selected = LayerLabel.objects.get(layerMapOptions=layerMapOptions)

    if request.POST:
        formset = layerLabelForm(request.POST, instance = layerLabel_selected)
        if formset.is_valid():
            instance = formset.save()
    else:
        formset = layerLabelForm(instance = layerLabel_selected)

    return render_to_response("basqui/manage_map_layerLabel.html", {'layer_label': layerLabel_selected, 'layerLabelformset': formset, 'layer': layerMapOptions.layer}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

forms.py:

```
class layerLabelForm(BetterModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(layerLabelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    class Meta:
        model = LayerLabel
        fieldsets =  [('Label Options:', {'fields': ['field', 'font','font_size', 'font_color', 'halo_radius', 'halo_color', 'offset_x', 'offset_y'], 'classes': ['module']}),]
```

Comment: What the issue here? If there's no model saved to the DB, then of course the form should be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to give the instance to the form when you want to edit a model instance that already exists in the db. If you just want a blank form for the model, then you just create the form without the instance keyword argument. I'll just summarize ModelForm usage below, but your code appears to need some changes.

Note: none of these are for a formset, which is different beast used when you want to provide multiples of a form.

```
# GET request to get a blank form to create a new instance
form = MyModelForm()

# POST request to save a new instance
form = MyModelForm(request.POST)
form.save()

# GET request to get a form prefilled with values from an existing model instance
form = MyModelForm(instance=my_model_instance)

# POST request to save changes to an existing model instance
form = MyModelForm(request.POST, instance=my_model_instance)
form.save()
```

For deleting, yes, you could use a ModelFormSet but you probably should only do that if you're presenting a list of models and are allowing the user to delete some of them. If you're only showing one model's form then just make a different view and POST the id/pk of the instance you want to delete. Make a "Delete" button somewhere on the page and send the request (jQuery makes this pretty easy or just use another HTML form) when the user clicks it. Here's a simple example that you wouldn't want to use but demonstrates the concept.

```
def delete_my_model(request):
    MyModel.objects.filter(pk=request.POST['pk']).delete()
    return HttpResponse()
```